# WordPress Plugin for video banner?

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to have a video banner on my WordPress site pages.  I saw the following site (http://pictoryproductions.com/) and they have exactly what I would like to do on my site.  However, I'm not sure what plugin they used to accomplish this.  Could anyone just point me in the right direction?

I'm fairly new to WordPress, so if anyone can suggest what plugin to use, or if there is functionality already in place in WordPress for this how I can use it to get the effect I want.

**UPDATE**

As per the requirement to show what has been done so far to achieve the result I want, I have created a PHP page that uses the HTML 5 video tags to embed the video I want, with the PNG overlay.  I then embed the page using an iframe tag from within WordPress.  The problem is I have to create a new PHP page for each WordPress page I want with this layout when it needs a different video and overlay png image.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid an opinionated answer on what I think is the best plugin to use, I just did a simple View Page Source on the site you posted and picked through to find where that video banner is displayed. It references a lot of classes and stuff labeled "mejs" which I think refers to a mediaelement.js plugin found here:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/